# show/hide div в динамически добавляемом поле не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который добавляет новую строку в таблице и удаояет ее. В каждом поле есть input file. Он скрыт и заменен на фото. После выбора фото происходит превью..

Проблема в том, что при добавлении нового поля фото не добавляется в него.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row2").click(function() {
    $('#addrQual' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><div class='image-upload'><label for='upload-file'><img class='attach-doc' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/015/337/675/small/transparent-upload-icon-free-png.png' style='height: 48px'></label><input id='upload-file' type='file' name='img[" + i + "]'/></div><div id='thumbnail'></div></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='name[]'></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='type[]'></td>");
    $('#tab_logicQual').append('<tr id="addrQual' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');

    i++;
  });
  $("#delete_row2").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addrQual" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });
});


$('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
  $('#upload-file').val("");
  $('.image-upload').css('display', 'block');

});
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  var filesVAR = this.files;
  showThumbnail(filesVAR);

}, false);

function showThumbnail(files) {
  var file = files[0]
  var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
  var pDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  pDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pDiv');
  thumbnail.appendChild(pDiv);

  image.setAttribute('class', 'img-preview');
  pDiv.appendChild(image)

  div.innerHTML = "x";
  div.setAttribute('class', 'closeDiv');
  pDiv.appendChild(div)

  image.file = file;
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
    return function(e) {
      aImg.src = e.target.result;
    };
  }(image))
  var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
    $('.image-upload').css('display', 'none');
  }
};
```

```css
.image-upload>input {
  display: none;
}

.attach-doc {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-preview {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.closeDiv {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 2px -10px;
}

.pDiv {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" type="button" id="add_row2">Add row</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" id="delete_row2">Delete row</button>

<table class="table" id="tab_logicQual">
  <thead>
    <tr VALIGN=MIDDLE ALIGN=CENTER>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='addrQual0' class="fieldGroup">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="image-upload">
          <label for="upload-file"><img class='attach-doc' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/015/337/675/small/transparent-upload-icon-free-png.png' style='height: 48px'></label>
          <input id="upload-file" type="file" name='img[]' />
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnail"></div>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='name[]'></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='type[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addrQual1'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Если вы про добавление строки с `id=upload-file`, то во первых, выборка стартует один раз и повторно данные не обновляются, во вторых, ID в документе должне быть уникальным.

Comment: @SwaD, не подскажите как сделать динамически уникальный id и обращаться только к нему?

Comment: Да как вам удобно... Хоть создайте переменную, туда положите `Math.random()` - вот вам и уникальный идентификатор. Хотите ,что то еще придумайте. МОжете просто создать элемент и сразу на него повесить слушали... Вариантов много, реализация зависит от конкретной задачи.